# Обработка изображений в php

Tags: php

Какие библиотеки Вы можете посоветовать для обработки изображений в php? Или может быть лучше воспользоваться стандартными функциями? Мне необходимо изменять размер изображений.

Comment: `$ convert -resize 600x400 source.jpg destination.jpg`

Comment: Не понял, что Вы хотели сказать?

Comment: [Масшатабирование изображений][1]
[1]:http://hashcode.ru/questions/94914/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: >> Не понял, что Вы хотели сказать?

грубо говоря: 

`system('convert -resize 600x400 source.jpg destination.jpg')`

должен быть установлен imagemagick и дописать полный путь к программе: convert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [WideImage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/):

```
$res = $img->resize(250, 1000);
```

Но для нее потребуется PHP 5.2+ и GD библиотека
Чтобы узнать версию php и проверить активна ли библиотека GD, используйте скрипт

```
<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

стандартной библиотеки GD для изменения размеров хватит)