# Обрезка и растягивание изображения

Tags: php

Есть скрипт который загружает картинки в на сервер и путь в бд прописывает. Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать так, чтобы каждое загружаемое изображение автоматические делалось 200*200, чтобы вручную постоянно это не проделывать постоянно? есть WideImage как его можно реализовать в данном коде

```
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Добавление obj файлла</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="load.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">  

 <input type="file" name="img">

  <a><input type="submit" name="add" value="Загрузить"></a>

 <a href="index.php">Вернуться</a>
 </form>
<?php
include('set.php');
include ('lib/WideImage.php');


$path = 'scr/';
$ext = array_pop(explode('.',$_FILES['img']['name']));
$pic = array_pop(explode('.',$_FILES['img']['name']));
$new_name = date("d.m.Y").'-'.$_FILES['img']['name'];
$full_path = $path.$new_name; 
echo $new_name;
echo '<br>';
echo $full_path;


if($_FILES['img']['error'] == 0){
if (($pic!="jpg")  &&  ($pic!="png")  &&  ($pic!="jpeg")){
    echo "Файл не был загружен, загрузите файл с расширением .jpeg/jpg/png";
exit();  

 }
else {

    $image = WideImage::load($new_name);
    $resized = $image->resize(200, 200);
    $resized->saveToFile($full_path);



if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $full_path)){
    }
    }
}



if(isset($_POST['add']))
{  

    $result = mysql_query('
INSERT INTO obj
(`img`)
VALUES
("' . $full_path . '")
');

    mysql_close;
    echo "Картинка добавлена";
}


?>
```

Выдает такую ошибку

> Warning: file_get_contents(21.12.2016-1.jpg)
>   [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in Q:\home\localhost\www\test\lib\WideImage.php on line 195
>
> Warning: unpack() [function.unpack]: Type c: not enough input, need 1,
>   have 0 in Q:\home\localhost\www\test\lib\vendor\de77\TGA.php on line
>   93
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'WideImage_InvalidImageSourceException' with message 'File
>   '21.12.2016-1.jpg' appears to be an invalid image source.' in
>   Q:\home\localhost\www\test\lib\WideImage.php:226 Stack trace: #0
>   [internal function]: WideImage::loadFromFile('21.12.2016-1.jp...') #1
>   Q:\home\localhost\www\test\lib\WideImage.php(184):
>   call_user_func(Array, '21.12.2016-1.jp...') #2
>   Q:\home\localhost\www\test\load.php(42):
>   WideImage::load('21.12.2016-1.jp...') #3 {main} thrown in
>   Q:\home\localhost\www\test\lib\WideImage.php on line 226

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Обработка изображений в php](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/97039/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-php)

Answer (score 2):

Нашел ответ на ваш вопрос [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/97039/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-php?rq=1)

`$res = $pic->resize(250, 1000);`

Для нее потребуется PHP 5.2+ и GD библиотека  [WideImage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: я попробую,расскажу о результате)спасибо!

Comment: $res = $pic->resize(250, 1000); мне только эта строчка нужна?

Comment: а как мне добавить это к себе 
  include 'lib/WideImage.php';
  $image = WideImage::load("1.jpg");
  $resized = $image->resize(200, 200);
  $resized->saveToFile("1small.jpg");
   я так понимаю что вместо 1.jpg и 1small.jpg нужны свои переменные или как?

Comment: @Michael Да, используйте названия какие угодно

Comment: @Michael точнее имена файлов полученные от клиента можете переименовывать для удобства

Comment: я пытаюсь в else перед if вставить
 include 'lib/WideImage.php';
  $image = WideImage::load($new_name);
  $resized = $image->resize(200, 200);
  $resized->saveToFile($full_path);
не получается

Comment: @Michael WideImage::load('big.png')->resize(200, 200)->saveToFile('small.jpg');

Comment: да но у меня картинки загружаются все время разные

Comment: @Michael Вы установили GD Библиотеку? http://ua2.php.net/manual/ru/image.setup.php

Comment: когда я выполняю это код отдельно он работает
include 'lib/WideImage.php';
  $image = WideImage::load("1.jpg");
  $resized = $image->resize(200, 200);
  $resized->saveToFile("1small.jpg");

Comment: @Michael не знаю в чём может быть проблема...

Comment: я изменил код добавил,посмотрите мб что увидите

Comment: @ThusMad если ответ на вопрос содержится в другом вопросе, то текущий вопрос стоит закрыть как дубликат(тревога -> должен быть закрыт -> этот вопрос уже был задан и имеет решение)

Comment: @Michael попробуйте просто WideImage.php без lib/

Comment: @ThusMad она у меня лежит в папке lib

Comment: @Michael попробуйте давать новое имя файлу после обработки